# Is it possible to run USSD code on Windows 10 Cellular Network interface to check data plan

Tags: windows-10, cellular-internet

I am using a Huawei data card connected to Windows 10. Is there a way to run USSD on it so that I can check my data plan?

[image: 1]

Comment: Get the recommended app and try

Comment: Like @RomeoNinov notes, the instructions are right there on your screen. Have you followed them yet? Did it work or not work for you?